# Why the two divs are not aligned?

Tags: html, css, alignment

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="top"></div>
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right"></div>
  <div id="clear"></div>
</div>
```

```css
#container{
  width:200px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-top:50px;   
}

#top{
  width:200px;
  height:20px;
  border:medium ridge #FFF;
}
#left{
  float:left;
  width:50px;
  height:20px;
  border:medium ridge #FFF;
}
#right{
  float:right;
  width:40px;
  height:20px;
  border:medium ridge #FFF;
}
#clear{
  clear:both;  
}
```

Why the `#right` and `#top` are not right aligned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because the `top` element is actually overflowing the bounds of the container, while the floated element `right` is being restricted to it.  The `top` element is overflowing the `container` because the border is not included in the width.  So `top` is actually occupying 204px.

Problem Illustrated via Example: http://jsfiddle.net/KhJ6e/2/

To fix, adjust `top` to account for the 2px border on each side. (subtract 4 from width of container) or specify width as `auto` depending on your intentions.

```
#top{
    width:196px;
    height:20px;
    border:medium ridge #FFF;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/KhJ6e/1/

Answer (score 2):

The top is wider than it's parent container

```
#top{
  width:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is how the width is calculated for the box model.  All elements on the screen have 4 components (inner to outer): content, padding, border, margin.  By default, the width includes only the content.  By adding the borders, top becomes larger than 200 pixels.  Using the developer tools in chrome, it was rendering as 206px.

There are two possible solutions, one is fudge the widths, or two modify the box model.  The first will work, but it is difficult to maintain.  Any small change can mess up the alignment.

A better solution is to use `box-sizing: border-box`.  By adding that CSS style, the width attribute will include content, padding, and border.  So, originally padding and border wrap around the *outside*, but with border-box, the encroach on the *inside*.

- Original: http://jsfiddle.net/deafcheese/Gv5BZ/
- Corrected (using
  `boz-sizing: border-box`): http://jsfiddle.net/deafcheese/Gv5BZ/1/
- box-sizing reference: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/